# MacBook Pro battery cycles is increased

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, energy

I have a MacBook Pro (2019), I usually work at home, so I use the MacBook with connected to energy but that the battery cycles is increased. This is normal? What is the best way to use a Macbook at home, connected to energy or using the battery?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal for the battery cycles to increase even if you are connected to a power supply. Laptops (like MacBooks) discharge and recharge their batteries a bit to increase their lifetime when they're connected to an external power source (citation needed; I've heard this many times but can't find a source for this quickly).

Comment: Basically, the laptop runs off the battery & the charger charges the battery. The laptop doesn't run off the charger. This means the battery is always in use, whether or not the charger is connected, so it will always show an increase in cycles with use.

Comment: Is the battery also in use even if the Power Source says 'Power Adapter' ?

Comment: Since I've used laptops without any battery, I don't think it's accurate to say that the power "runs off the battery & the charger charges the battery". But the battery is "in use" even when connected to an external power source insofar that as part of the battery health management, some power may be drawn from the battery. Li-Ion batteries are complicated. For example, even though your Mac or iPhone may report a "100%" charge, it is never _physically_ 100% charged, and likewise, never 0% charged. Both would damage the cells.

Comment: Though some computers will run without a battery, not all will. If there is no battery, a computer can crash at high loads, starved of power. The battery's job is to be able to maintain output at high loads. The charger's job is to trickle-charge the battery. Therefore there can be some crossover, but essentially my initial statement still stands.

Comment: Most Mac laptops with CPU throttle if the battery is removed, to avoid a greater power draw than the charger can supply. I'd agree with Tetsujin. The battery powers the computer; the charger refills the battery.